# Log to different file with log4cxx

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

I want to log to different files in my code.

How can i do that in Log4cxx with xml configuration or programatically in code...

- Suppose that I have 1.k,k+1,..n  components.
- They run in the same application
- I want  component  k log to Logger-k, k+1  component log to Logger-k+1
  at the same time

Update:

Logger.addAppender() approach:

```
log4cxx::helpers::Pool p; 

std::string paramAppender = "appxNormalAppender";
std::string paramFileName = "\\Logs\\MyLog.txt";

LOG4CXX_DECODE_CHAR(logAppender, paramAppender );
LOG4CXX_DECODE_CHAR(logFileName, paramFileName );


FileAppenderPtr fileAppender = 
logger->getLoggerRepository()->getRootLogger()->getAppender(logAppender);

if(fileAppender!= NULL)
{


    fileAppender->setFile(logFileName);

    fileAppender->activateOptions(p);

}
```

This does not work because

> Suppose that i set FileName to Logger-k for k component, it logs to
>   Logger-k, then i set file name to Logger-k+1 for compoent k+1, then both component k,
>   and k+1 log the same loggerk+1 file. It seems last file name overrides or effects all others...

And

> All compoenent compenent 1, ...compoeent k, componentk+1,....
>   component n are in the same application...

Answer (score 3):

Create Each of the Loggers as normal, and then for each logger add a FileAppender set to the desired file via the Logger.addAppender() method.

Comment: It does not work...I put an update on my question...May be i do something wrong...So i put some code...

Comment: you are trying to reset the root level logger's file name and thus where everything logs. You need to add a seperate FileAppender to each component to log to the specified file.

Answer (score 2):

You do need to create separate appenders for you loggers. In my example i've created **afile1** and **afile2** appenders. I have also created two loggers : **my.logger1** and **my.logger2**. When you use **my.logger1** it logs to **mylog1** file, When you use **my.logger2** it logs to **mylog2** file.

Here is my **log.properties** file:

```
log4cplus.appender.afile1.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.afile1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [ %c{1} ] [ %-5p ] %m%n
log4cplus.appender.afile1=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.afile1.File=mylog1.log
log4cplus.appender.afile1.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4cplus.appender.afile1.MaxBackupIndex=2

log4cplus.appender.afile2.layout=log4cplus::PatternLayout
log4cplus.appender.afile2.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [ %c{1} ] [ %-5p ] %m%n
log4cplus.appender.afile2=log4cplus::RollingFileAppender
log4cplus.appender.afile2.File=mylog2.log
log4cplus.appender.afile2.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4cplus.appender.afile2.MaxBackupIndex=2

log4cplus.logger.my.logger1=INHERIT, afile1
log4cplus.additivity.my.logger1=false
log4cplus.logger.my.logger2=INHERIT, afile2
log4cplus.additivity.my.logger2=false
```

Here is an example programm:
example.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <log4cplus/logger.h>
#include <log4cplus/loglevel.h>
#include <log4cplus/configurator.h>
#include <log4cplus/fileappender.h>

#define MYLOG1_INFO(logEvent) LOG4CPLUS_INFO (log4cplus::Logger::getInstance("my.logger1"), logEvent)
#define MYLOG2_INFO(logEvent) LOG4CPLUS_INFO (log4cplus::Logger::getInstance("my.logger2"), logEvent)

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    try
    {
        log4cplus::PropertyConfigurator::doConfigure("log.properties");
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
    std::cerr<<"Exception occured while opening log.properties\n";
    return -1;
    }
    MYLOG1_INFO("hello world!");
    MYLOG2_INFO("hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is Makefile( i suppose my log4cplus is built in parent dirrectory):

```
CXXFLAGS+=-I$(abspath ../log4cplus-1.0.4/include)
all: example.o
    $(CXX) $^ $(abspath ../log4cplus-1.0.4/src/.libs/liblog4cplus.a) -lpthread -o test
```

Try this example and you should understand how appenders works

Log4cplus is mostly like log4j. so you can read basic principles log4j.
And To get classes names you got to visit [log4cplus.sourceforge.net](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/)

About log format. Documentation for log4cplus is available only in doxygen . so here you can read about [formating in pattern layout](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1PatternLayout.html) 
And if you want to log process id , than you should use %i in your layout conversion pattern
example:

```
...
log4cplus.appender.afile2.layout.ConversionPattern=[%i] %m%n
...
```

It will log process id and message

Comment: sorry, wrote about log4cplus. But believe me, it's better than log4cxx

Comment: It seems that log4cplus is "Dead".[January 2011 last release] and it also suffer from lack of documenttaion. I may choose log4cplus if i can do with it this: Check my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082413/add-process-id-to-log-file-name-in-log4cxx

Comment: latest release of log4cxx was in 2008-04-03 http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/changes-report.html
and latest realease of log4cplus was in 2011.
More log4cxx have 0.10 version and log4cplus have version 1.04
So it seems like log4cxx is much more dead project

Comment: Answering your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082413/add-process-id-to-log-file-name-in-log4cxx
You can do it in log4cplus

Comment: You are right about log4cxx .It is more "dead" than log4cplus.

Comment: If "yes" to my question so how with log4cplus? If you have working sample then  update your answer here that show how to do this and 50 bounty will be yours. I am looking for practical answers.

Comment: I do not want to log process Id. What i want is create new file name at each process automatically like in log4net. So my logs will be process safe easily.Read question again

Comment: Suppose that process X will create file MyLog+Xid and process Y create a file MyLog+Yid

Comment: log4cplus can't provide this possibility. sorry my misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 1):

For dynamic components try this:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

#include <log4cxx/Logger.h>
#include <log4cxx/LogManager.h>
#include <log4cxx/xml/domconfigurator.h>
#include <log4cxx/FileAppender.h>
#include <log4cxx/SimpleLayout.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/transcoder.h>


void func(int k) {
    std::string strName = "Log." + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(k);
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr log = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(strName);
    LOG4CXX_DECODE_CHAR(fileName, strName + ".log");
    log4cxx::FileAppenderPtr appender(new log4cxx::FileAppender(new log4cxx::SimpleLayout, fileName, false));
    log->addAppender(appender);

    LOG4CXX_INFO(log, strName);

    log->removeAppender(appender);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    log4cxx::xml::DOMConfigurator::configure("trace.xml");
    if(log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("Log")->getAllAppenders().empty()) {
        std::cout << "failed to config log4cxx" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr log = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger("Log");

    boost::thread_group threadGroup;
    for(int k = 0; k != 3; ++k) {
        threadGroup.create_thread(boost::bind(func, k));
    }
    threadGroup.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

with simple trace.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout"/> 
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="all"/>
    </root> 

    <category name="Log">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </category>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution for dynamic logging using thread context in log4cxx with class `MDC`, after big frustration with current solutions. It basically allows to have an `instanceid` prefix added to the `File` property of a `FileAppender`. It requires a custom `FileAppender` to be properly compiled and defined before loading of a configuration file. Works with usual old log4cxx 0.10.0 version. It can be used with the following snippet:

```
#include <XFileAppender.h>

void PushInstance(const std::string &instanceid)
{
    MDC::put("__ITRInstanceId", value);
}

void PopInstance()
{
    MDC::remove("__ITRInstanceId");
}

int main()
{
    {
        auto logger = Logger::getLogger("Test1");
        PushInstance("user1");
        logger->log(log4cxx::Level::getInfo(), "Info");
        PopInstance();
    }

    {
        auto logger = Logger::getLogger("Test2");
        PushInstance("user1");
        logger->log(log4cxx::Level::getWarn(), "Warning");
        PopInstance();
    }

    // Imagine "Test1" and "Test2" used from different
    // threads acting as "user1"

    // Following line will ensure writers will be closed when "user1"
    // e.g. is logging out
    XFileAppender::CloseIstanceWriters("instance1");
    return 0;
}
```

Can be used with this property configuration file:

```
# Default log filename. Can be overridden by system properties
LogFilename=File.log

# Appenders
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %-6p: %m%n

log4j.appender.USER=org.apache.log4j.XFileAppender
log4j.appender.USER.File=${LogFilename}
log4j.appender.USER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.USER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}] %-6p: %m%n

# Root
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, stdout

# Classes
log4j.logger.Test1=INFO, USER
log4j.additivity.Test1 = false
log4j.logger.Test2=INFO, USER
log4j.additivity.Test2 = false
```

XFileAppender header:

```
// Copyright (c) 2019 Francesco Pretto
// This file is subject to the Apache License Version 2.0

#pragma once

#include "libdefs.h"
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>
#include <log4cxx/fileappender.h>

namespace log4cxx
{
    class ITR_LOGGING_SHARED_API XFileAppender : public FileAppender
    {
    private:
        struct InstanceWriter
        {
            typedef std::shared_ptr<InstanceWriter> Ptr;
            InstanceWriter(helpers::Pool& p);
            helpers::Mutex Mutex;
            helpers::WriterPtr Writer;
        };
        typedef std::unordered_map<LogString, XFileAppender *> AppenderIdentities;
    public:
        DECLARE_LOG4CXX_OBJECT(XFileAppender)
        BEGIN_LOG4CXX_CAST_MAP()
            LOG4CXX_CAST_ENTRY(XFileAppender)
            LOG4CXX_CAST_ENTRY_CHAIN(FileAppender)
        END_LOG4CXX_CAST_MAP()

        XFileAppender();

    public:
        void close() override;
        void append(const spi::LoggingEventPtr &event, helpers::Pool &p) override;
        void activateOptions(helpers::Pool &p) override;

    public:
        /**
        Clear all registered writers

        NOTE: It doesn't close them. This is useful example when reloading configuration
         */
        static void ClearWriters();

        /**
        Close all writers linked to instance
         */
        static void CloseIstanceWriters(const LogString &instanceid);

    private:
        InstanceWriter::Ptr getInstanceWriter(helpers::Pool &p);
        void CloseWriter(const LogString &istanceid);
        void closeWriter(InstanceWriter &writer);
        void closeWriter(helpers::Writer &writer);
        void closeWriters();
        helpers::WriterPtr createWriter(const LogString &instanceid, helpers::Pool& p);
        helpers::WriterPtr createWriter(const File &file, helpers::Pool& p);
        static void removeAppenderIstances(const LogString &appname, std::vector<LogString> &instanceIds);

    private:
        XFileAppender(const XFileAppender&);
        XFileAppender& operator=(const XFileAppender&);

    private:
        static helpers::Mutex s_mutex;
        static std::unordered_map<LogString, AppenderIdentities> s_appenderIdentities; // NOTE: Guarded by s_mutex
    private:
        bool m_failedWriter;                                                           // NOTE: Guarded by mutex
        helpers::WriterPtr m_writer;                                                   // NOTE: Guarded by mutex
        std::unordered_map<LogString, InstanceWriter::Ptr> m_instanceWriters;          // NOTE: Guarded by mutex

    }; // class XFileAppender
    LOG4CXX_PTR_DEF(XFileAppender);

}  // namespace log4cxx
```

XFileAppender source:

```
// Copyright (c) 2019 Francesco Pretto
// This file is subject to the Apache License Version 2.0

#include "XFileAppender.h"
#include <log4cxx/helpers/synchronized.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/transcoder.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/loglog.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/stringhelper.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/bufferedwriter.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/bytebuffer.h>
#include <log4cxx/helpers/fileoutputstream.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace log4cxx;
using namespace log4cxx::spi;
using namespace log4cxx::helpers;

static Pool s_pool;
Mutex XFileAppender::s_mutex(s_pool);
unordered_map<LogString, XFileAppender::AppenderIdentities> XFileAppender::s_appenderIdentities;

XFileAppender::XFileAppender()
{
    m_failedWriter = false;
}

void XFileAppender::close()
{
    synchronized sync(mutex);
    if (closed)
        return;

    closeWriters();
    closed = true;
}

void XFileAppender::append(const LoggingEventPtr &event, Pool &p)
{
    InstanceWriter::Ptr instance;
    {
        synchronized sync(mutex);
        if (closed)
            return;

        instance = getInstanceWriter(p);
        if (instance == nullptr)
        {
            // Try to use non instanced writer
            if (m_failedWriter)
                return;

            if (m_writer == nullptr)
            {
                m_writer = createWriter(LogString(), p);
                if (m_writer == nullptr)
                {
                    m_failedWriter = true;
                    return;
                }
            }

            LogString msg;
            layout->format(msg, event, p);
            m_writer->write(msg, p);

            if (getImmediateFlush())
                m_writer->flush(p);

            return;
        }
    }

    // NOTE: From now, we can release the appender istance lock

    if (instance->Writer == nullptr)
    {
        // This is a failed writer
        return;
    }

    LogString msg;
    layout->format(msg, event, p);

    synchronized syncWriter(instance->Mutex);
    instance->Writer->write(msg, p);

    if (getImmediateFlush())
        instance->Writer->flush(p);
}

void XFileAppender::activateOptions(helpers::Pool &p)
{
    synchronized syncWriter(mutex);
    closeWriters();
    // Do nothing more. We lazily create writers later
}

void XFileAppender::ClearWriters()
{
    synchronized lock(s_mutex);
    s_appenderIdentities.clear();
}

void XFileAppender::closeWriter(InstanceWriter &writer)
{
    synchronized syncWriter(writer.Mutex);
    // If it's a valid writer. It could be a failed one 
    if (writer.Writer != nullptr)
        closeWriter(*writer.Writer);
}

// Stripped from WriterAppender.cpp
void XFileAppender::closeWriter(Writer &writer)
{
    try
    {
        // before closing we have to output out layout's footer
        // NOTE: Using the object's pool since this is a one-shot operation and
        // pool is likely to be reclaimed soon when appender is destructed.
        if (layout != NULL)
        {
            LogString foot;
            layout->appendFooter(foot, pool);
            writer.write(foot, pool);
        }

        writer.close(pool);
    }
    catch (IOException& e)
    {
        LogLog::error(LogString(LOG4CXX_STR("Could not close writer for WriterAppender named ")) + name, e);
    }
}

void XFileAppender::closeWriters()
{
    vector<LogString> instancesToDelete;
    for (auto &pair : m_instanceWriters)
    {
        auto &writer = pair.second;
        closeWriter(*writer->Writer);
        instancesToDelete.push_back(pair.first);
    }

    removeAppenderIstances(getName(), instancesToDelete);
    m_instanceWriters.clear();

    if (m_writer != nullptr)
    {
        closeWriter(*m_writer);
        m_writer = nullptr;
    }
}

// Stripped from FileAppender.cpp
WriterPtr XFileAppender::createWriter(const LogString &instanceid, helpers::Pool& p)
{
    LogString fileName = getFile();
    if (fileName.empty())
    {
        LogLog::error(LogString(LOG4CXX_STR("File option not set for appender ["))
            + name + LOG4CXX_STR("]."));
        LogLog::warn(LOG4CXX_STR("Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?"));
        return nullptr;
    }

    File file(fileName);
    if (instanceid.length() != 0)
    {
        auto name = file.getName();
        auto parent = file.getParent(p);
#if WIN32
        file = parent + LOG4CXX_STR("\\") + instanceid + LOG4CXX_STR("_") + name;
#else
        file = parent + LOG4CXX_STR("/") + instanceid + LOG4CXX_STR("_") + name;
#endif
    }

    try
    {
        return createWriter(file, p);
    }
    catch (IOException& e)
    {
        LogString msg(LOG4CXX_STR("createWriter("));
        msg.append(fileName);
        msg.append(1, (logchar)0x2C /* ',' */);
        StringHelper::toString(fileAppend, msg);
        msg.append(LOG4CXX_STR(") call failed."));
        errorHandler->error(msg, e, ErrorCode::FILE_OPEN_FAILURE);
        return nullptr;
    }
}

// Stripped from FileAppender.cpp
WriterPtr XFileAppender::createWriter(const File &outFile, helpers::Pool& p)
{
    bool append = getAppend();
    bool writeBOM = false;

    if (StringHelper::equalsIgnoreCase(getEncoding(),
        LOG4CXX_STR("utf-16"), LOG4CXX_STR("UTF-16")))
    {
        // don't want to write a byte order mark if the file exists
        if (append)
        {
            writeBOM = !outFile.exists(p);
        }
        else
        {
            writeBOM = true;
        }
    }

    OutputStreamPtr outStream;

    try
    {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getPath(), append);
    }
    catch (IOException& ex)
    {
        LogString parentName = outFile.getParent(p);

        if (!parentName.empty())
        {
            File parentDir;
            parentDir.setPath(parentName);

            if (!parentDir.exists(p) && parentDir.mkdirs(p))
            {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile.getPath(), append);
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    // if a new file and UTF-16, then write a BOM
    if (writeBOM)
    {
        char bom[] = { (char)0xFE, (char)0xFF };
        ByteBuffer buf(bom, 2);
        outStream->write(buf, p);
    }

    WriterPtr newWriter(WriterAppender::createWriter(outStream));

    if (getBufferedIO())
    {
        newWriter = new BufferedWriter(newWriter, getBufferSize());
    }

    if (layout != NULL)
    {
        LogString header;
        layout->appendHeader(header, p);
        newWriter->write(header, p);
    }

    return newWriter;
}

void XFileAppender::removeAppenderIstances(const LogString &appname, vector<LogString> &instanceIds)
{
    synchronized lock(s_mutex);
    if (s_appenderIdentities.size() == 0)
        return;

    for (auto &instanceid : instanceIds)
    {
        auto found = s_appenderIdentities.find(instanceid);
        if (found == s_appenderIdentities.end())
            break;

        found->second.erase(appname);
        if (found->second.size() == 0)
        {
            // All appenders for this instance were closed
            s_appenderIdentities.erase(found);
        }
    }
}

XFileAppender::InstanceWriter::Ptr XFileAppender::getInstanceWriter(Pool &p)
{
    LogString instanceid = MDC::get(LOG4CXX_STR("__ITRInstanceId"));
    if (instanceid.length() == 0)
        return nullptr;

    auto &writer = m_instanceWriters[instanceid];
    if (writer == nullptr)
    {
        // NOTE: We must use instance pool here otherwise there are
        // crashes, don't know exactly why
        writer.reset(new InstanceWriter(pool));
        writer->Writer = createWriter(instanceid, p);
        synchronized lock(s_mutex);
        auto &appenders = s_appenderIdentities[instanceid];
        appenders[getName()] = this;
    }

    return writer;
}

void XFileAppender::CloseIstanceWriters(const LogString &instanceid)
{
    synchronized lock(s_mutex);
    auto found = s_appenderIdentities.find(instanceid);
    if (found == s_appenderIdentities.end())
        return;

    for (auto &pair : found->second)
    {
        auto appender = pair.second;
        appender->CloseWriter(instanceid);
    }

    s_appenderIdentities.erase(found);
}

void XFileAppender::CloseWriter(const LogString &istanceid)
{
    synchronized sync(mutex);
    auto found = m_instanceWriters.find(istanceid);
    closeWriter(*found->second);
    m_instanceWriters.erase(found);
}

XFileAppender::InstanceWriter::InstanceWriter(Pool &p)
    : Mutex(p) { }

IMPLEMENT_LOG4CXX_OBJECT(XFileAppender)
```