# C++ thread name map and log4cxx

Tags: c++, multithreading, log4cxx

With `std::thread`, it is now trivial to keep a list of threads names in the program state (either by wrapping the thread, or by using a singleton to manage the thread list.)

I am starting to use log4cxx for my logging, and I'd like to have it display the thread name. However, this means I cannot use the PatternLayout. The thread numbers aren't very useful on their own.

What is the best way to do this? Am I stuck with just outputting a map, or can I override `PatternLayout`/`ConversionPattern` in a clever way to do what I want? And if I overload it, how do I point to the class in the config file? Or can I possibly add a conversion character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your  thread names using MDC before setting logger in your program

```
 MDC::put( "threadName", threadNameString);
```

Then at XML config

```
   <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%X{threadName} "/>
    </layout>
```

So at each log message your thread name will apear.

For more info check answer of this question: [Add process id to log file name in log4cxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082413/add-process-id-to-log-file-name-in-log4cxx)